# Loop through function and stack the output into a dataset in R

Tags: r, function, loops, dplyr

I wrote a function that runs a linear model and outputs a data frame. I would like to run the function several times and stack the output. Here is a hypothetical dataset and function:

```
data = data.frame(grade_level = rep(1:4, each = 3),
                  x = rnorm(12, mean = 21, sd = 7.5),
                  y = rnorm(12, mean = 20, sd = 7)) 

func = function(grade){
  model = lm(y ~ x, data=data[data$grade_level == grade,])
  fitted.values = model$fitted.values 
  final = data.frame(grade_level = data$grade_level[data$grade_level == grade],
                     predicted_values = fitted.values)
  final
  }
```

Currently, I run the function over each grade in the dataset:

```
grade1 = func(1)
grade2 = func(2)
grade3 = func(3)
grade4 = func(4)

pred.values = rbind(grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4)
```

How can I use a loop (or something else) to more efficiently run this function multiple times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `purrr` package has a really handy function for this. `map` works like the `apply` family of functions in Base R (which operate like a `for` loop in many ways). The `_dfr` specifies that you want to call `rbind` on the results before returrning.

This function says: "loop through `c(1, 2, 3, 4)`, each time calling `func()` on each, then `rbind` the results at the end and give the `data.frame` back to me."

```r
purrr::map_dfr(1:4, func)
```

Comment: Was literally typing in the same answer when you posted yours. You're a quick typer

Comment: @AdamK Upvote from my end. One liner instead of writing a loop.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `lapply()`

```
 do.call("rbind", lapply(1:4, func))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find a solution using a loop an `rbind` below.

```
data = data.frame(grade_level = rep(1:4, each = 3),
                  x = rnorm(12, mean = 21, sd = 7.5),
                  y = rnorm(12, mean = 20, sd = 7)) 

func = function(grade){
  model = lm(y ~ x, data=data[data$grade_level == grade,])
  fitted.values = model$fitted.values 
  final = data.frame(grade_level = data$grade_level[data$grade_level == grade],
                     predicted_values = fitted.values)
  return(final)
}

grades <- c(1:4)

pred.values <- data.frame()
for (i in grades) {
  
  temp <- func(grade = i)
  pred.values <- rbind(pred.values, temp)
  
}
```

Will give

```
> pred.values
   grade_level predicted_values
1            1         30.78802
2            1         22.79665
3            1         29.56155
4            2         14.60050
5            2         14.56934
6            2         14.71737
7            3         16.97698
8            3         17.71697
9            3         18.95596
10           4         15.18937
11           4         16.56399
12           4         22.49093
```